# How to get child model one row data in drf serilaizer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models

```
class Ad(ActivatorModel, TimeStampedModel):
     ........
class AdImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my serializer is

```
class MyAdsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ads.models.Ad
```

how can I get ad primary image in the above serializer

Answer (score 2):

Add an explicit serializer inside of `MyAdsSerializer`.

Adjust `AdImage` to have an explicit [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) on the `ad` `ForeignKey`:

```
class AdImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ad_images')
    #                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Change `MyAdsSerializer` like to have a serializer beneath it and then explicitly name your fields:

```
class MyAdsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ad_image__images = serializers.CharField(
        source='ad_images.image', 
        many=True, 
        read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ads.models.Ad
        fields = ('id', 'other_ad_field', 'ad_image__images'
```

Comment: No AdImage has foreignkey
`class AdImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: Alrighty.  Then you use a `related_name`.  FYI, you will can have multiple `AdImage`'s for one `Ad` since `ad` is a `ForeignKey`.  If you change the `ad` field to be a `OneToOneField`, then it will limit the number of `AdImages` per `Ad` to 1.